# Android How to show offers end time counter?

Tags: android, date, timer

I'm trying to show some offer end time counter in my app which takes the end time string from my backend and its suppose to display the remaining days:hours:minutes:seconds by comparing it with current date but i really get lost !!

i hope that some one go through it

her is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    String offerenddate = "2017-04-01 12:56:50";
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        Date oldDate = dateFormat.parse(offerenddate);

        Date currentDate = new Date();
        long diff = oldDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
        long seconds = diff / 1000;
        final long minutes = seconds / 60;
        final long hours = minutes / 60;
        final long days = hours / 24;
        new CountDownTimer( diff,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                tv.setText("Time Remaining : "+days+" - "+hours+":"+minutes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tv.setText("Closed");
            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the Library,countdownView https://github.com/iwgang/CountdownView.